# Palindrome test for 1->1->2->1 should return false, but returns true

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am looking at LeetCode problem [234. Palindrome Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/):

> Given the head of a singly linked list, return true if it is a palindrome.

I first made a function that'll return the reversed linked list, and then I checked it with the original list.

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    ListNode* reverse(ListNode* head)
    {
        if(head==NULL||head->next==NULL)
            return head;
        
        ListNode* rest=reverse(head->next);
        head->next->next=head;
        head->next=NULL;
        
        return rest;
    }
    
    
    bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head)
    {
        ListNode* p=head;
        ListNode* node2=reverse(p);  
        
        while(head!=NULL && node2!=NULL)
        {
            if(head->val!=node2->val)
                return false;
          
            
            head=head->next;
            node2=node2->next;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
};
```

But it is returning `true` in cases where it should return `false`, like for `1->1->2->1`.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Your function `reverse` breaks the original list. You will want to make a copy of the list somewhere. (Before applying `reverse` or in the function `reverse`)

Comment: You may recieve better feedback by asking your question on the Leetcode forums.

Answer (score 0):

After these statements

```
ListNode* p=head;
ListNode* node2=reverse(p);
```

the original list is broken. That is if the initial list is not empty  then after calling the member function `reverse` `head->next` is equal to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

`reverse` will mutate the only list you have, so after the reversal, `head` points to the tail of the list. Its `next` member has been set to `nullptr`. You cannot expect to move two pointers in opposite directions along one and the same singly linked list. There is only one direction possible.

<sup>(Side note: in C++ don't use `NULL` for pointers, but `nullptr`).</sup>

The naive solution is to create a new, second list that is the reversal of the original list, without changing anything to the original list. Then the `while` loop will work as you expected it. The downside of such a solution is that it needs to duplicate each node -- requiring O(n) auxiliary space.

A bit smarter is to split the original list into two halves, and reverse only the second of these two. Then again, the loop will work.

And, when avoiding the O(n) auxiliary space, you should also make the `reverse` function iterative instead of recursive, as the recursive version uses O(n) stack space.

Have a go at it.

I provide here a spoiler solution:

> `class Solution {
>  private:
>      ListNode* reverse(ListNode* head)
>      {
>          ListNode* prev = nullptr;
>          ListNode* current = head;
>          ListNode* temp;
>          while (current) {
>              temp = current->next;
>              current->next = prev;
>              prev = current;
>              current = temp;
>          }
>          return prev;
>      }
>      ListNode* mid(ListNode* head)
>      {
>          ListNode* mid = head;
>          ListNode* fast = head;
>          while (fast != nullptr && fast->next != nullptr) {
>              mid = mid->next;
>              fast = fast->next->next;
>          }
>          return mid;
>      }
>      bool compareCommon(ListNode* head, ListNode* head2)
>      {
>          while (head != nullptr && head2 != nullptr)
>          {
>              if (head->val != head2->val)
>                  return false;
>              head = head->next;
>              head2 = head2->next;
>          }
>          return true;
>      }
>  public:
>      bool isPalindrome(ListNode* head) {
>          return compareCommon(head, reverse(mid(head)));
>      }
>  };`